# Use the htaccess file or other method and GEOIP for language redirection with codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, geoip

I am facing a problem, I try to redirect the user to a different URL depending on his country of origin using the .htaccess file and GEOIP, I use Codeigniter 3 when I try to follow this tutorial:

> https://support.cloudways.com/en/articles/5126366-how-to-use-geoip-with-your-application

A redirection error appears, I don't know how to implement this code? Is using the `.htaccess` file for the redirection the best solution?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You may consider using the ```redirect``` function based on the GEOIP headers.